# Perfect Tense Stative verbs

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense

I'd like you to tell me which one of my following sentences is correct. I am not sure if I have to use the past simple or present perfect.

I'd add that I want to talk about something which is still true. I'm still in love with the person I talk to!

---

1. **I've loved** you as soon as I saw you

   Or
2. **I loved you** as soon as I saw you

---

3. **I've loved** you from the first day

   Or
4. **I loved** you from the first day

---

I need you to tell me, but I think present perfect must be correct since we say :

**I've loved** her since I met her

Thank you very much

Comment: You need to distinguish between references to a **point in time**, like _as soon as I saw you_ and references to a **length of time**, like _from the first day_. You can use the perfect with lengths of time because that's what it's for; but you can't use it with a point in time. That's what the past tense is for, among other things. This is not a matter of stativity so much as it is of time reference; statives always refer to lengths of time, but they're not the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are talking about something which is **still true**, you need to use present perfect:

> ### We use the present perfect:
>
> - for something that **started in the past** and **continues in the present**:
>
> *They've been married for nearly fifty years.*
>
> *She has lived in Liverpool all her life.*
>
> <...>
>
> (https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect)

Now let's return to your question. Sentences 2 and 4 are not what we need because we are talking about something which is still true, as we said (i.e. *"I loved you"* means *"I loved you in the past, but now I don't"*). Sentences 1 and 3 are perfectly fine.

Please note that present perfect can also be used in other situations. You can follow the link to the British Council site (or, perhaps, this link - https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html) for more details. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)